# Help me identify an SMD diode? MURS360T3G?

Tags: diodes, surface-mount

there is the 'U3J' text on it ? this is the MURS360T3G?
and what polarity is ?

[image]

[image]

after replace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the [MURS360T3G](https://octopart.com/datasheet/murs360t3g-onsemi-15150), and should have Cathode at notch by convention.  Although it would be nice if the datasheet confirmed this.

Comment: thx. In a new MURS360T3Gs' a line determines the cathode

Comment: "Polarity: Notch in Plastic Body Indicates Cathode Lead" says the first page of the datasheet

Comment: Polarity: Polarity Band on Plastic Body Indicates Cathode Lead